# how to save text with multilines in textarea in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's the view which I'm using to enter the multiline article
I wish that you can also told me how to save the text properties such as bold italic too because it makes me very confused.

```
@model WEBSITI.Models.article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm( "Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted, the asp.met mvc framework will inspect the request body to see whether it has any potentially dangerous content as HTML markup(***Think about script injection***). If it detects any dangerous content,the Request Validation module will throw an error. This is by design

To explicitly allow the form posting with Html tags inside the property value, you may decorate your specific property with the `AllowHtml` attribute

```
public partial class article
{
    [AllowHtml]       
    public string bodyofarticle { set; get; }

    //other properties here
}
```

This will tell the framework to exclude this property from the above request validation.

I suggest you follow [PascalCasing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) while writing C# code ( Ex : `Article` instead of `article`)

Comment: sir so i can use the replace method to change the \n with <\br>  when i'm adding new article???

Comment: Why you want to replace ? If you are supporting html type content., you should consider using an rich text editor .

Comment: i don't know but i replace it to change the insertion because the user will press enter instead of print "<br/>" but when i'm showing the data it print <br /> instead of print newline